# Angular ngx-datatable cellTemplate not loading

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

I'm trying to override the template of an ngx-datatable cell. So in my template (html) file i'm setting a small view for this. To test if the template works i'm just displaying the value with starts around it:

```
<ngx-datatable
    class="material"
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="columns"
    headerHeight="45">
</ngx-datatable>
<ng-template #roleTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value" let-i="index">
  <strong> **{{ value }}** </strong>
</ng-template>
```

In my component im using ViewChild to get the template and give it to my datatable.
`@ViewChild('roleTemplate') roleTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;`

```
public columns = [
        { name: 'Name', prop: 'displayName' },
        { name: 'Email', prop: 'emailAddress' },
        { name: 'Role', prop: 'role', cellTemplate: this.roleTemplate },
        { name: 'Status', prop: 'status' },
    ];
```

Only thing the [documentation](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs.html) says:

> **cellTemplate: TemplateRef**
>
> Angular TemplateRef allowing you to author custom body cell templates

However it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you need to move your columns initialization inside `ngOnInit` like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.columns = [
    { name: 'Name', prop: 'displayName' },
    { name: 'Email', prop: 'emailAddress' },
    { name: 'Role', prop: 'role', cellTemplate: this.roleTemplate },
  ];
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FxZo4SxKLbCPxmNTveXr?p=preview)**

Comment: That link is no longer working - https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/tree/master/demo/templates

Comment: I'm using v^17 of ngx-datatable. ngOnInit() didn't do it for me. The cell templates were being ignored. Moving the column initialization to ngAfterViewInit() made everything magically work

Answer (score 12):

You have to initialize your columns inside `ngAfterViewInit`. I was facing the same problem and I realized the `templateRef` was undefined, even if I initialized the columns inside `ngOnInit`.
So I moved the columns initialization to `ngAfterViewInit` and it works just great. Like following in Angular 9:

```
import { ... AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.columns = [
        { name: 'Name', prop: 'displayName' },
        { name: 'Email', prop: 'emailAddress' },
        { name: 'Role', prop: 'role', cellTemplate: this.roleTemplate },
        { name: 'Status', prop: 'status' },
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Getting the same issue in ng10 - oninit not working but afterviewinit is.

Comment: Same. I tried so many things and my cell templates were being ignored and instead ngx-datatable was just putting the raw values (without the template) in there. After I moved the initialization to ngAfterViewInit() everything magically started working

Comment: Another thing that's a gotcha, in case this helps anyone reading this... make sure props whose values are boolean or number are assigned without quotes (i.e. maxWidth: 80, sortable: false, etc) or they'll be ignored too.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Angular 7 and i had the exact problem you described - on the exact same sample code!
As suggested in another answer, moving the `column` population into `ngOnInit` did not make any difference for me. What worked for me was a restart of the web server - in my case i killed the running `ng serve` and started again. Sounds strange, but it worked for me. Looks like this is some sort of a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem here with initialization and assignment a variable in one row

```
public columns = [
    { name: 'Name', prop: 'displayName' },
    { name: 'Email', prop: 'emailAddress' },
    { name: 'Role', prop: 'role', cellTemplate: this.roleTemplate },
    { name: 'Status', prop: 'status' },
];
```

You need to drop to different rows initialization and assignment like this

```
columns: any[];


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columns = [
        { name: 'Name', prop: 'displayName' },
        { name: 'Email', prop: 'emailAddress' },
        { name: 'Role', prop: 'role', cellTemplate: this.roleTemplate },
        { name: 'Status', prop: 'status' }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're most probably using a nested template and thus angular is not able to get a reference.

So move your column templates from here

```html
<ng-template #someParent>
  <ng-template #columnXYZ></ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

to here

```html
<ng-template #someParent></ng-template>
<ng-template #columnXYZ></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the columns using ngAfterViewInit, and use the Promise object to prevent error "NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked"

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        this.columns = [
            { name: 'Name', prop: 'displayName' },
            { name: 'Email', prop: 'emailAddress' },
            { name: 'Role', prop: 'role', cellTemplate: this.roleTemplate },
        ];
    });
}
```